# Preventing unclear ambiguity in grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In the following grammar:

```
expr : r1 EOF
     | r2 EOF
     ;

r1 : '1' L1 'x' ;
r2 : '1' L2 'y' ;

L1: 'a' ;
L2: 'a' ;
```

When I'm parsing an expression

```
1ay
```

I expect the parser to create the appropriate parse tree, however I'm getting the following error:

> line 1:2 mismatched input 'y' expecting 'x'

Why can't it be parsed correctly? Can I give it directives to do so?

Parsing code:

```
private static void parse(String str) 
{
    ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(str);
    AmbLexer lexer = new AmbLexer(input); 
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); 
    AmbParser parser = new AmbParser(tokens);
    ParseTree tree = parser.expr();
    System.err.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step in parsing is creating token stream based on lexer rules. The token is created with the rule which will first match. So in your case every 'a' will be L1. And as r1 is only parser rule containing L1 it cannot match the input, because rule 'r1' is expecting 'x', not 'y'.

Therefore lexer rules must be ordered so the special and more specific will be before more vague one. Rules as string, numbers will be in the end, but rules as 'func', 'class' will be before them.

To solve the problem, merge the L1 and L2 into one rule and use it in both parser rules.